# Web scraping with python -selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all href contents from the class "news" (Url is mentioned in the code) , I tried this code, but it is not working...

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

Base_url = "http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/stocks/abb-india-ltd/overview/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_position(-10000,-10000)
driver.get(Base_url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='news'):  
    a = div.findAll('a')   
    print(a['href'])
```

Thank you

Comment: I think your issue is that the page doesn't have any `div`s with news class. It has `article`s with news class.

Comment: @jayant do you know any method to scrape all those href's ? i want all those  href contents(latest news)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you want is located inside the frame:

```
<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://hindubusiness.cmlinks.com/Companydetails.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022" id="compInfo" height="600px">...</iframe>
```

So, first you'll have to switch to that frame. You can do this by adding these lines:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame('compInfo')
```

Complete code (making it headless):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Base_url = "http://www.thehindubusinessline.com/stocks/abb-india-ltd/overview/"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(Base_url)
driver.switch_to.frame('compInfo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
for link in soup.select('.news a'):  
    print(link['href'])
```

Output:

```
/HomeFinancial.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022&Cname=ABB-India-Ltd&srno=17040010444&opt=9
/HomeFinancial.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022&Cname=ABB-India-Ltd&srno=17038039002&opt=9
/HomeFinancial.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022&Cname=ABB-India-Ltd&srno=17019039003&opt=9
/HomeFinancial.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022&Cname=ABB-India-Ltd&srno=17019038003&opt=9
/HomeFinancial.aspx?&cocode=INE117A01022&Cname=ABB-India-Ltd&srno=17019010085&opt=9
```

Comment: can we hide that chrome pop up window?

Comment: Yes we can. Search how to add arguments with chrome_options. And use `--headless`.

Comment: Or even better, use PhantomJS

Comment: In case of choosing any headless browser, I think chrome is better than phantomjs as the earlier has fewer issues than the latter when it comes to initiate click. However, the above script can run headlessly now @python.

Comment: i got error for the above mentioned headless chrome program. i'm a beginner. can you please tell me , how to set that driver path.

Comment: Use like this in that specific line:`driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ar\Desktop\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Comment: @Topto 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/AnacondaProjects/Websites/headless.py", line 21, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
  File "C:\AnacondaProjects\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to install lxml parser

Comment: The issue you are facing is path related so there are two options: 1. create a new post describing the barrier you are facing and drop a link here 2. Or, stick to the way you were doing first.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
for div in soup.find_all('article', 'news'):
    a = div.findAll('a')
    links = [article['href'] for article in a ]
    print(links)
```

Comment: i want href's from  company news